# auto-vectorization using GCC does not work

Tags: vectorization

I'm compiling the following code, named 'example.C' with and without auto-vectorization, the running time are identical. Could this be that my CPU does not support it or I didn't compile it correctly?

```
int main(){
  const unsigned int ArraySize = 10000000;
  float* a = new float[ArraySize];
  float* b = new float[ArraySize];
  float* c = new float[ArraySize];

  for (unsigned int j = 0; j< 200 ; j++) // some repetitions
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < ArraySize; ++ i)
      c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
```

Here is how I compile it without auto-vectorization. 
    g++ example.C -o example

with the auto-vectorization: 
    g++ example.C -o example  -ftree-vectorize

Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: This is the first time I ever heard of this option but looking at the docs, there's a -ftree-vectorizer-verbose option which might help you (and also a test suite).

Comment: I tried that one and it doesn't work either. The -ftree-vectorizer-verbose option should also output certain information. In my case, it's quiet.

Comment: If you compile your code with just `-O2` it gets optimized away completely: https://godbolt.org/z/KLkQGk

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean "-ftree-vectorize" need to be used with "-O2" option. It's not clear from the "https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html", where -O2 option does not include the "-ftree-vectorize" but "-O3" does.